# ESLint - require let or const instead of var (no-var)

Tags: javascript, eslint

How to disable the rule of discouraging the use of var and encouraging the use of const or let instead on ESlint?

Comment: It is boolean flag. Set it to true or false in eslint.json config file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `package.json` (assuming that is what you are using), include:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
        "no-var": 0
    }
}
```

[`no-var`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var) is the rule, and `0` [sets the rule to "off"](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules).

If you're not using `package.json`, you can set the the same in an `.eslintrc.js`, or, on a per-file basis, include a comment at the top of the file `/* eslint no-var: 0 */`.

All this comes from the [ESlint Configuration Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

Answer (score 5):

Extending the previous answer, all of these variants work for comments at the beginning of the block:

```
/* eslint no-var: off */
...

/* eslint no-var: */
...

/* eslint no-var: 0 */
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The valid cases for using `var` are extremely limited, so it's good to consider disabling the `no-var` rule only on specific lines where's it's justified.

The `//eslint-disable-line [RULE]` comment can be used to turn off a single rule on a single line.

For example, if you're working with the *Google Tracking* `dataLayer` array:

```js
declare global { var dataLayer: unknown[] }  //eslint-disable-line no-var
...
globalThis.dataLayer.push(args);
```

For more details:
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#disabling-rules